# It's sends 4 times the amount of members

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want my bot in a certain server to send a dm to a random member every 10 minutes. And when my bot has sent everyone from the server a dm it sends a complete message.

But when i start the bot it sends 4 times the amount of members

```
if (message.content.startsWith(botconfig.prefix + 'dmall')) {
    console.log("demo");
    var list = message.guild.members.array();
    sendMessage(list);
  }
});


function sendMessage(list) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list.length);
    }

    console.log("I'm done, mate!");
    sendMessage(list);
  }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
demo
4 (is the amount of the members)
4
4
4
I'm done mate!
```

Comment: Why do you claim that the message is sent four times? Is it because the number `4` is logged four times (assuming `list` -> [4, 4, 4, 4]) ?

Comment: Idk 4 is the amount members in my server idk why it sends 4 times the same

Comment: It's because you are running a `for` loop on `list.length` which is `4`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  console.log(list.length);
}
```

tells Javascript to run the statement:

```
  console.log(list.length);
```

`list.length` times.  If `list.length` is `4` which it appears to be here, then you will see in the console

```
4
4
4
4
```

That's what the code was instructed to do.

I don't see any reason why you'd put that in a loop unless you want to output each array element separately.  So, if you want to just output the length once, then replace this:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  console.log(list.length);
}
```

with this:

```
console.log(list.length);
```

---

In addition, if you were to use a `for` loop, you MUST declare all variables that you use. So, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
```

is very dangerous.  It relies on a higher scoped `i` which can easily conflict with other higher scoped `i` variables and create hard-to-figure out bugs.  Every `for` loop should declare it's own loop variable as in:

```
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
```

If you run your code in strict mode (which you should), the above for loop declaration would likely cause an error (which is a good thing because you'd immediately see the coding error and fix it).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong here.
For of: JavaScript variable scoping messing you up ([Different example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396665/javascript-for-loop-issue-when-using-ajax-the-loop-has-access-even-when-condi/59396882?noredirect=1#comment104983022_59396882)

Second of all: setTimeout is not the same as setInterval.

Completely fixing your issue would be:

```js
 // Use the discord API
let users = ['justme']
function getUsers() {
    // Mutate just to display a new one each time
    users = [...users, users.length.toString()];
    return users
}

function notifyUsers() {
    // Retrieve all users now
    const currentUsers = getUsers()
    // Send a message to each user
    currentUsers.forEach(user => sendMessage(user))
    console.log('I have sent everyone a message')
}

function sendMessage(user) {
  console.log(`Sending message to ${user}`)
}

// Start the application by looping every <whatever>
setInterval(() => notifyUsers(), 1000)
```